Calling Firebase's HttpsCallable function before creating a Messaging instance is triggering token cleanup and throwing errors
In my react/firebase app, I am calling an HttpsCallable function when a user is unauthorized and I am getting these token-related errors below. These occur when I call the HttpsCallable callFunction. The breakdown is occurring here when firebase is trying to create the function's context. I don't set up messaging until the user is authenticated and has granted Notification permission so null is passed for messaging and this seems to be triggering a token cleanup process that is failing. I'm a little stumped on how to fix this. I would have expected this to be true since null would be passed for messaging.
const getCallableFunction = (functionName: string, data?: string) => {
    const functions = getFunctions();
    const callable = httpsCallable(functions, functionName);
    return async () => {
        try {
            await callable(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`error calling ${functionName}`, error);
        }
    };
};

const callFunction = getCallableFunction(
    'callFunction',
    'example@example.com',
);

callFunction();

The console errors:
DELETE [url to my firebase project removed] 404 (Not Found)


FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while unsubscribing the user from FCM: Requested entity was not found. (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed). (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed).

FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while unsubscribing the user from FCM: FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while unsubscribing the user from FCM: Requested entity was not found. (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed). (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed).
    at requestDeleteToken (index.esm2017.js:433:1)
    at async getTokenInternal (index.esm2017.js:499:1)
    at async ContextProvider.getMessagingToken (index.esm2017.js:344:1)
    at async ContextProvider.getContext (index.esm2017.js:370:1)
    at async callAtURL (index.esm2017.js:559:1)
    at async file.ts:18:4

POST [url to my firebase project removed] 401 (Unauthorized)

There is no issue invoking the cloud function and all of the HttpCallables that I call when messaging is set do not have these issues. These errors aren't actually breaking anything but I would like to get rid of them. Does anyone see what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

Given that you link into the source code for the client SDK a couple of times, and the SDK is generating errors that aren't clear for this situation or covered in the documentation, it seems like maybe you actually have a bug report to file in that repo.
